# How to refactor the scala code?

Tags: java, scala

Actually, I wrote a scala script which is sorting the function based on some parameter. Look at below code snip:

```
object TestTypes {
     type SortFn = ((String, TestMetricFields)) => Double
     case class TestMetricFields(maths: Int, science: Int)
}

trait TestMarks {
   def sName: String
   def getSortFun(): SortFn
}

object TestMarkStudent extends TestMarks {
   override def sName: String= "xxx"
   override def getSortFun(): SortFn = {
      input: (String, TestMetricFields) => input._2.maths + input._2.science
  }
}
```

Here I want to avoid the use `._2` in above code. How to rewrite the scala code?

I tried the following but I am failed.

```
override def getSortFun(): (String, TestMetricFields) => SortFn = {
     (sName: String, testField: TestMetricFields) => {
        input: (String, TestMetricFields) => 1.0 * testField.maths + testField.science
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me to refactor the code without using `._2`?

Comment: What do you have to avoid using `_2`?

Answer (score 2):

You can write it like this:

```
 override def getSortFun(): SortFn = { case(_, fields) => 
   fields.maths + fields.science
 }
```